# Translation of "cirons"

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, littérature

I'm reading *Guignol's Band II* by L.-F. Céline, and there's a dancing scene in which the narrator has to hit the bar bed, prompting the beat. As he was injured in the war, he is quickly exhausted, and to describe this particular moment appears the word "*cirons*."

"J'en sens plus mes membres d'épuisement! Je suis baratiné! (...) Je suis pompé! je résiste plus aux *cirons*! la férocité d'âme et corps! (...) 'Les *cirons* alors? les *cirons*? si tu t'arrêtes c'est la mort!" (CÉLINE, 2016, p. 363).

According to the dictionary, *ciron* is "cheese mite", "woodworm", but this meaning doesn't seem appropriate to the context created by the writer.

As Céline is known by his use of slang and expressions from the early 20th century, could anyone please help me to understand the meaning of this word in the sentences above?

Comment: My two cents: (Par extension), en particulier par référence à Blaise Pascal. Être d’une extrême petitesse.
(Par extension) Personne qui agit avec petitesse.
https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ciron

Comment: Can you gives the whole extract? What about the bits left out?

Comment: As it follows: "J'en sens plus mes membres d'épuisement! Je suis baratiné! Il passera 'armoïde' tout seul, vainqueur des Arkiosaures, des monstres! Je veu plus de croupionnage! Je suis pompé! je résiste plus aux cirons! la férocité d'âme et corps! Tout seul qu'il ira se faire foutre! Ah! mais il l'entend pas ainsi 'Les cirons alors? les cirons? si tu t'arrêtes c'est la mort!" (CÉLINE, 2016, p. 363).
Taking the opportunity, your extensive knowledge in French and the complexity of this passage, could you maybe also help me to understand the meaning of "armoïde" and "croupionnage"?

Answer (score 1):

Croupionnage semble vouloir dire « coucher », façon Cézane :)

I think the whole sense is that the author don’t wan’t to go anymore to the brothel with his mate.
I think « Cirons » may mean « body louse ». Other graphemes includes « Gau », « got », « toto »… (François Dechelette, l’Argot des Poilus).

Answer (score 0):

"J'en suis baratiné!": Céline uses the verb "baratter" (to turn milk into cream by beating it) as an -er verb on the "baratiner" model. I'm left with no energy.

"Croupionnage" is a neologism based on "croupion", ass, and by extension here, a rythmic dance.

"Ciron" is a small insect and by extension, the smallest entities in the universe.